# Waterline contains on association attributes?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js, contains, waterline

I have a model which is populated with users. So I want to make a find where one of the users = someString.

So using Waterline I can do this

```
        Partie.find().populate('users').where({category:{'contains':'sport'}}).exec(function(e,r){
        console.log(r);
        res.json(200,r);
    });
```

But how do I make the contains on 'users'? Which is an array.

```
"users": [
  {
    "username": "firstUser",
    "createdAt": "2015-07-30T15:33:57.662Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-07-30T15:33:57.662Z",
    "id": "55ba43e58cce9ee80865271b"
  },
  {
    "username": "someUsername",
    "createdAt": "2015-08-04T12:14:50.291Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-08-04T12:14:50.291Z",
    "id": "55c0acba2d1502ed2faf2b3b"
  }
],...
```

Not sure if that's even possible. Feel free to suggest alternatives

Comment: To be clear: are you are trying to populate multiple levels down? Or are you simply trying to filter the user array?

Comment: No it is already populated for my needs. So I have a "game" populated by users. So yes I want to filter the user array. Something like Game.find().populate('users').where({users.username:{'contains':'someUser'}}) But that is invalid

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a second argument into populate with containing criteria for the query, eg:

```
 Partie.find().populate('users', {where: {username: "someUsername"}})...
```

In my experience (using latest waterline) the example above only populates users that match the given usernames into the Partie object.

However, on my machine it does NOT restrict what 'Parties' are returned from the search query (perhaps this has something to do with my waterline/postgres adapter version). I solved this issue by filtering the complete array after it returned (using lodash):

```
 res.json(_.filter(parties, function(party){
    // Pluck all usernames and check if 'someUserName' is attending this party
    return _.contains(_.pluck(party.users, 'username'), 'someUserName');
 }));
```

Note that using a filter like example above is inadvisable for large datasets!